# Validating in app purchase locally for non consumable in Flutter with official plugin

Tags: android, ios, flutter, in-app-purchase

I am trying to validate locally in app purchase of non consumable in Flutter with their official plugin `in_app_purchase`.

I get `localVerificationData` string in `verificationData` in `PurchaseDetails` object. But I have no idea how to use this `localVerification` string in this verification process.

I found in [this Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/choosing_a_receipt_validation_technique#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH105-SW1) saying that

> Validating locally requires code to read and validate a PKCS #7
> signature, and code to parse and validate the signed payload

But still I need help with code samples to do this in Flutter.